# Created a new embed field automatically once one is full? [VB]

Tags: vb.net, discord, discord.net

> ```
> Private Async Function cmdList() As Task
>     Dim m = Context.Message
>     Dim u = Context.User
>     Dim g = Context.Guild
>     Dim c = Context.Client
>
>     Dim words As String = ""
>
>     Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
>         .Title = $"Wallpaper keyword list",
>         .ImageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/vc241Ku.jpeg",
>         .Description = "The full list of keywords in our random wallpaper list",
>         .Color = New Color(masterClass.randomEmbedColor),
>         .ThumbnailUrl = g.IconUrl,
>         .Timestamp = Context.Message.Timestamp,
>         .Footer = New EmbedFooterBuilder With {
>                 .Text = "Keyword Data",
>                 .IconUrl = g.IconUrl
>             }
>         }
>
>     For Each keyword As String In wall.keywords
>
>         words = words + keyword + " **|** "
>     Next
>     embed.AddField("Full list", words)
>
>     Await m.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
> End Function
> ```

This is my command to get every word from an array and put it on a field. What I want to know is how do I make it so once the field gets full it'll automatically add a new one and continue with the list. This might be a little far-fetched but just don't know how to go about this. Sorry if I can't understand any of the answers. I'm still a little new to coding on Discord.net and well vb in general.

Comment: when building your words string, check if the length of the new word to be added will cause the string to exceed the maximum length of the field. If it will exceed, don't add it to the string and instead add the string to the field...reset `words` using the new word continue the same logic until you're finished.

Comment: that's going to be interesting to figure out. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ixaqubelat.php From my attempt. Not sure what exactly I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modification of you hastebin code

```vb
Dim row As Integer = 0
Dim words As String = String.Empty

For Each keyword As String In wall.keywords
    'If appending the keyword to the list of words exceeds 256
    'don't append, but instead add the existing words to a field.
    If words.Length + keyword.length + 7 > 256 Then
        row += 1
        embed.AddField($"List #{row}", words) 'Add words to field
        
        'reset words
        words = String.Empty
    End If

    words = words + keyword + " **|** "
Next

'The add condition within the for loop is only entered when we are
'about to exceed to field length. Anything string under the max 
'length would exit the loop without being added. Add it here
embed.AddField($"List #{row + 1}", words)

Await m.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", False, embed.Build())
```

While it does not change any of the logic, you could consider using a `StringBuilder`